# Detecting blinks of a horse from side view with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

This is rather a theoretical question than asking for specific code issue.

I have done a bit of facial landmark detection using Haar Cascades, but this time I have a different type of video on my hands. It's a side view of a horse's eye (camera is mounted to the side of the head) so essentially what I see is a giant eye. I tried using Haar Cascades but it's no use, since there is no face to be detected in my video.

I was wondering what the best way to detect the eye and blinks would be on this horse? Do I try and customize a dlib facial mark detector? I didn't find much information on animal landmarks.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: if you can manage it, it'd help to have a picture of what the camera sees. One with the eye open, one with it closed. It sounds like the image is mostly going to be of the eye. Assume the eye isn't the same color as the eyelid, you can count the number of pixels of a certain color and register sudden changes as blinks.

Comment: Hi, yes, this is the direct view from the camera - https://ibb.co/4dRsMNw . Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: have a look at deep learning object classification+localization, detection, segmentation or keypoint/landmark detection

Comment: If you have the video can you post that? Then we can try out a solution and check if it works.

Comment: Hello, sure, this is one of my videos - https://www.dropbox.com/s/hb5g16lk910szur/video.mov?dl=0 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an object tracker to continue locating the eye after drawing a bounding box around it on the first frame.

I created a set width and height bounding box since we can roughly assume that the eye isn't growing or shrinking relative to the camera. When drawing the bounding box for the tracker, we have to include more than just the eye since it would otherwise lose track of the object whenever they blink.

I looked for whether the saturation of the bounded area dropped below a threshold in each frame as a check for whether or not they blinked. The blue box is the bounding box returned by the tracker, the green box is the area I'm cropping and checking the saturation level of.

Here's a graph of the saturation level over the course of the video
[image]

You can clearly see the areas where they blinked

Here's a (heavily compressed to make the 2mb limit) gif of the result

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# tuplifies things for opencv
def tup(p):
    return (int(p[0]), int(p[1]));

# returns the center of the box
def getCenter(box):
    x = box[0];
    y = box[1];
    x += box[2] / 2.0;
    y += box[3] / 2.0;
    return [x,y];

# rescales image by percent
def rescale(img, scale):
    h,w = img.shape[:2];
    h = int(h*scale);
    w = int(w*scale);
    return cv2.resize(img, (w,h));

# load video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("blinking.mov");
scale = 0.5;

# font stuff
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
org = (50, 50);
fontScale = 1;
font_color = (255, 255, 0);
thickness = 2;

# set up tracker
tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create(); # I'm using OpenCV 3.4
backup = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create();

# grab the first frame
_, frame = cap.read();
frame = rescale(frame, scale);

# init tracker
box = cv2.selectROI(frame, False);
tracker.init(frame, box);
backup.init(frame, box);
cv2.destroyAllWindows();

# set center bounds
width = 75;
height = 60;

# save numbers
file_index = 0;

# blink counter
blinks = 0;
blink_thresh = 35;
blink_trigger = True;

# show video
done = False;
while not done:
    # get frame
    ret, frame = cap.read();
    if not ret:
        break;
    frame = rescale(frame, scale);

    # choose a color space
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv);
    channel = s;

    # grab tracking box
    ret, box = tracker.update(frame);
    if ret:
        # get the center
        center = getCenter(box);
        x, y = center;

        # make box on center
        tl = [x - width, y - height];
        br = [x + width, y + height];
        tl = tup(tl);
        br = tup(br);

        # get top left and bottom right
        p1 = [box[0], box[1]];
        p2 = [p1[0] + box[2], p1[1] + box[3]];
        p1 = tup(p1);
        p2 = tup(p2);

        # draw a roi around the image
        cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 3);
        cv2.rectangle(frame, tl, br, (0,255,0), 3);
        cv2.circle(frame, tup(center), 6, (0,0,255), -1);

        # get the channel average in the box
        slc = channel[tl[1]:br[1], tl[0]:br[0]];
        ave = np.mean(slc);

        # if it dips below a set value, then trigger a blink
        if ave < blink_thresh:
            if blink_trigger:
                blinks += 1;
                blink_trigger = False;
        else:
            blink_trigger = True;

        # draw blink count
        frame = cv2.putText(frame, "Blinks: " + str(blinks), org, font, fontScale, 
                            font_color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA);

    # show
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame);
    key = cv2.waitKey(1);

    # check keypress
    done = key == ord('q');
```